# Add reply to Slack form in specific Google Sheet row

Tags: google-sheets, slack, slack-api

I have created a Slack channel with a workflow where people can submit a simple form with their questions. I added a step in the workflow that adds a new row to a Google Sheet document, with the information from the form, including the datetime. I would like to add another step that links up the reply to a specific form posted in the channel with the original form. Can someone help me with that?

If that cannot be done via the workflow builder or other apps, I am happy to explore using the Slack API with Python.